# RestTemplate is not considering cacheConfig provided by Apache http client

Tags: spring, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

Sample code :

```
final CacheConfig cacheConfig = CacheConfig.custom()
  .setMaxCacheEntries(50)
  .setMaxObjectSize(800)
  .setHeuristicCachingEnabled(true)
  .setHeuristicDefaultLifetime(5)
  .build();

final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = CachingHttpClients.custom()
  .setCacheConfig(cacheConfig)
  .build();

final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
restClient.getForObject("serverUri"); //this is never hitting the cache.
```

Look like apacheHttpClient never invoked ?

Comment: And it should because? You are recreating the cache and everything each time you need it. Instead configure a `RestTemplate` and reuse it if you want to be able to use a cache. Don't create a new instance each time you need one.

Comment: Sorry was not clear in quesiton! yes I am doing the same as suggested !   restClient.getForObject("serverUri"); //this is never hitting the cache. is always called with same restTemplate instance.

Comment: Not judging from your code you posted here. That code will never cache. If that isn't the code you are using then post some code that you are actually using instead of incomplete and not used code.